# Visual Code how can I activate the virtual environment automatically?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Maybe a simple question, but I cannot figure it out. I work within Visual Studio Code on a MacBook. Within a directory I create a virtual environment and have activated that with source `.venv/bin/activate` scripts and everything works fine.
In the terminal I see `(.venv) (base) gaston@MacBook-Pro WebScraping %`

When I start visual code another time and open this same directory I do not see the (.venv) so I again give manually the command to activate.

My question is there a way to activate the virtual environment automatically when opening the directory?

Comment: have you selected a Python interpreter in VSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something within settings and now it works.
When I open VSC now it opens the directory and the right environment, just the way I wanted it.

Took me some while to figure what finally did the trick:
I opened settings `Command + ,` typed env in the search box. Scrolled through the results until I saw:

```
Python > Terminal: Activate Env In Current Terminal
```

and checked the checkbox. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**VS Code Default Python Interpreter Path**

You can do this in a number of ways. If your goal is to have the virtual environment selected immediately at the launch of VS Code, you will have to target that virtual environment as the Python Interpreter in VSC.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

`System Preferences->Settings->Python: Default Interpreter Path`

You'll want to point it to your virtualenv Python installation, likely something like:

`envFolder/bin/python3`

**VS Code Launch Configuration Python Interpreter**

You can also set a specific launch configuration so that VSCode will still use your system Python instance by default; however, specific launch configurations will have the virtual environment specified.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging